# What's the easiest way to kill Fawkes?

Tags: fallout-3

So just for fun, as I've now gotten all the level/alignment achievements, I decided to try and kill Fawkes, who's waiting in Underworld. I knew he'd be tough -- when VATS shows a mini-nuke barely scratching him, that's reason to pause and think about what you're doing.

According to the [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fawkes), though, Fawkes only has about 500 hit points -- less than I do at this stage of the game. Yet -- and I admit this may be due to my own bad aim, as I usually try to do combat in VATS -- it seemed to take me 47 mini-nukes and 4,000 Electron Charge Packs for me to kill him. (And I was using stealth boys and doing as much as I could as "sneak attacks" for criticals -- 100 sneak, 75 big guns.)

So, aside from the obvious early way to kill him (with the terminal outside his cell in Vault 87), what's the easiest way to kill Fawkes?

Comment: What difficulty setting are you on?

Comment: @Raven: Normal. Although now that I'm at level 30, and XP don't matter anymore, I suppose I could turn it down to Very Easy. :)

Comment: I should note, I did manage to kill him, but it seemed really odd that he was harder to kill than an army of behemoths. :)

Comment: Well, doesn't the radiation from the nuke launcher heal him? If you launched 47 nukes at him and THEN tried to gatling him down, it's conceivable that there was enough environmental radiation left over from your nukes that he could heal up from some of your damage.

Comment: @Raven: Not that I'm aware of, though I could be wrong. I just double-checked the Wiki -- [Fawkes](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fawkes), [East Coast Super Mutants](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_87_super_mutant) and the generic [Super Mutants](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Super_mutant) articles -- and didn't see anything that indicated that Fawkes (nor any super mutant) would heal from radiation. I was just launching mini-nukes because of their 4-figure damage count. :)

Comment: -1 for not realizing Fawkes was female.  +2 for sheer tenacity/cohones/awesomeness.  I thought I remembered that some creatures were healed by radiation, and I *thought* it might be super mutants...but maybe it's just ghouls.

Comment: And it's that tough on *normal* difficulty? Egad. I played through on the toughest difficulty, and there was *NOTHING* that could even take close to that level of damage and survive. Glad I didn't decide to try and take her out.

Comment: @beska: For the record, according to the [Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fawkes), "Contrary to a comment about Fawkes' gender made by his voice actor, lead designer Emil Pagliarulo has confirmed 'No, Fawkes was absolutely a male. This was a mistake. Wes gave an interview and he was mistaken. Trust me, Fawkes is and was male.'" And yes, Fawkes was ludicrously hard to kill. :) I don't even know how many stimpacks I went through, but my hunch is probably 40 or 50. (And I didn't save after doing it; it was just for giggles.)

Comment: @John: Oh, fine. I wonder if he would be easier to kill off after he (sigh) joins you. If not, you'd think that just about every battle with him at your side would be essentially unloseable, assuming you were willing to just hide while he took em all out. Hmm.

Comment: @beska: Yep, my attempt to kill him was well after completing the entire main storyline. He may be easier to kill when he's unconditionally following you through Vault 87, but it looked to me like once he got out and starting hanging in Underworld, he became a nigh-invincible killing machine.

Comment: @John: So was my answer not what you were looking for?

Comment: @thethin: It's up there, but I haven't tried it yet, so I haven't marked accepted. I keep hoping other strategies will come up, but I guess most players haven't tried to go full-psycho in F3. :)

Comment: @John: No worries, just checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try is stacking 100 mines in a pile around him, or walk him into the pile after creating it, then shoot the pile with a mini-nuke. It toasts mysterious stranger, so it should kill Fawkes as well.

For reference:

.

Comment: Clever! (And I never thought to try killing Mysterious Stanger. If you do so, does his body remain for looting purposes?)

Comment: No I don't think so, he is labelled as a mission critical character (like in Oblivion) so he will be unconscious for a short period of time then revive. You can see the text "Mysterious Stranger is Unconscious" in the video after he blows up.

Comment: @John Rudy however there's this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFyrypHa0Fo. I'm guessing he spawned him through the console for looting.

Comment: How'd it work John?

Comment: That did it, too ...

Answer (score 5):

Reverse pickpocketing a *single* frag mine did it, too. I know, I'm a jerk to kill Fawkes, but it was fun. Especially to hear him scream, "Run away!" Then he blew up.

Comment: +1 for using only 1, although I'm not saying anything against 100 frag mines being awesome :D I wonder if putting frags in people's trousers is an auto-kill?

Comment: @thethinman: I'm thinking it is. Which is actually useful knowledge, if you think about it. Can you reverse-pickpocket monsters? (I'm thinking super mutant overlords, ghoul reavers and albino radscorpions.) I never keep explosives around -- but might if I could get away with that instead of wasting my 15,000+ rounds of EC packs on 'em ...

Comment: Also, did you know you can only reverse pickpocket a single live frag into someone? Subsequent frags you add to the person are just being traded in instead of rigged to blow ...

Comment: @thethinman: Definitive answer from [The Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Pants_Exploded): Exploding pants are always lethal. Also, Fawkes is so tough at level 30 because apparently [companions scale with the player](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3_Companions) -- so think a Super Mutant who's achieved level 30, and suddenly it makes sense that he's like an army of behemoths.

Comment: @John: In terms of reverse-pickpocketing the bigguns they don't have inventories, so it doesn't work. Read it on the page you gave but letting everyone else know.

Comment: @John: Oblivion did the level scaling too (still pretty sure it's the same engine), but it made leveling up a waste of time because the monsters scaled up better than you did. Thank god Fawkes is on our side.

Comment: @thethin: Yeah, it definitely won't work on most monsters. But -- I haven't tried it -- it seems like it should work on overlords, since they should have an inventory to handle their grab weapon scripting?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way EVER to kill him is to pick-pocket him and place a grenade or mine into his inventory, seconds later, a dead Fawkes, and there is no gattling laser in his inventory :(